# Why Generators are exhaustive and Lists/Tuples are not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, iterable

First of all i have to say i read lot of SO posts before coming to this one because I could not find what I was looking for or maybe I didn't understood.
So here it goes

I kind of understand what Iterables and Iterators are. So any container object like Lists/Tuples/Sets which contains items, which you can iterate over are called Iterables. Now to iterate over the Iterables you need Iterators and the way it happens is because of `__iter__` method which gives you the Iterator object for the type and then calling the `__next__` on the Iterator object to extract the values.

So to make any object iterable you need to define **iter** and **next** methods, and i suppose that is true for Lists as well. But here comes the weird part which I discovered recently.

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
hasattr(l1, "__next__")
Out[42]: False
g = (x for x in range(3))
hasattr(g, "__next__")
Out[44]: True
```

Now because the lists do support Iterator protocol why the `__next__` method is missing from their implementation, and if it indeed is missing then how does iteration for a list work ?

```
list_iterator = iter(l1)
next(list_iterator)
Out[46]: 1
next(list_iterator)
Out[47]: 2
next(list_iterator)
Out[48]: 3
next(list_iterator)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RJ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-49-56e733bbb896>", line 1, in <module>
    next(list_iterator)
StopIteration

gen0_iterator = iter(g)
gen_iterator = iter(g)
next(gen_iterator)
Out[57]: 0
next(gen_iterator)
Out[58]: 1
next(gen_iterator)
Out[59]: 2
next(gen_iterator)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RJ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-60-83622dd5d1b9>", line 1, in <module>
    next(gen_iterator)
StopIteration
gen_iterator1 = iter(g)
next(gen_iterator1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RJ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-62-86f9b3cc341f>", line 1, in <module>
    next(gen_iterator1)
StopIteration
```

I created an iterator for a list and then called next method on it to get the elements and it works.

1. Now if the previous `hasattr(a, "__next__")` returns a `False` then how we are able to call next method on the iterator object for a list.
2. Now the original question which made me think all this, no matter how many times i iterate over the list, it doesn't exhaust and calling the `iter()` gives back a new iterator object everytime, but in case of generator this does not happen, and once the generator has exhausted, no matter how many times you call `iter()` it will always gives you back the same object which already has raised the `StopIteration` exception and again this is true because an iterator once raised a `StopIteration`, it always will, but why it does not happen with lists.

Further this is in sync with what python docs says for [conatiner.__ iter__](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#container.__iter__) that `container.__iter__` gives you the iterator object for the type and [iterator.__ iter__](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__iter__) and `iterator.__iter__` gives you the iterator object itself, which is precisely the reason that calling the `iter()` on generator returns the same object over and over again. But why and more importantly how ?

One more thing to observe here is

```
isinstance(l1 , collections.Iterator)
Out[65]: False
isinstance(g , collections.Iterator)
Out[66]: True
```

So this suggests that there is some implementation difference b/w Iterables and Iterators, but i could not find any such details, because both have `__iter__` and `__next__` methods implemented, so from where does this variation in behavior comes. So is it that `__iter__` for iterables returns something different from what is returned by `__iter__` of iterables(generators). If some can explain with some examples of `__iter__` for Iterables and Iterataors that would be really helpful. Finally some puzzle about `yield`, since that is the magic word which makes a normal function a generator (so a type of iterator), so what does `__iter__` and `__next__` of `yield looks like.

I have tried my level best to explain the question, but if still something is missing, please do let me know i will try to clarify my question.

Comment: Because tuples and lists are **sequences**, so can be indexed at random. Iterators are not sequences, and you can create iterators for many more things than just sequences. Like an [infinite counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count). Sequences are *iterable*, meaning that you can create (new) iterators for them.

Comment: As to why `list` doesn't have a `__next__()`, iterable objects aren't required to have `__next__()`; they just need `__iter__()`. The object _returned by `__iter__()`_ has to have a `__next__()` method.

Comment: *to make any object iterable you need to define `__iter__` and `__next__` methods*: no, you only need the `__iter__` method. **Iterators** need `__next__`, *iterables* do not.

Comment: In other words: you have the iterable and iterator types confused. *Iterable* --> can **potentially** be iterated over, you can produce an iterator for this object. *Iterator* --> the object doing the iterating.

Comment: *Iterable* -> you use the `__iter__` method to produce the iterator. *iterator* -> you use the `__next__` method to do the iterating. Iterators also have a `__iter__` method, because that makes it so much easier to handle both types (just call `iter()` on either and you know you have something with a `__next__` method returned).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bit different than that. *iterables* have an `__iter__` method that returns an iterator. *iterators* have a `__next__` method (and usually also have `__iter__` so that `iter()` works on them - but that's not required).

Lists are iterable:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> hasattr(l, "__iter__")
True
>>> hasattr(l, "__next__")
False
>>> l_iter = iter(l)
>>> hasattr(l_iter, "__next__")
True
>>> hasattr(l_iter, "__iter__")
True
>>> l_iter == iter(l_iter)
True
```

And give you new iterators that run through the e each time you use them

```
>>> list(l)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list(l)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> l_iter = iter(l)
>>> list(l_iter)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list(l_iter)
[]
 each time you use them

>>> list(l)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list(l)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> iter(l) == iter(l)
False
```

But the list iterator itself is one shot

```
>>> l_iter = iter(l)
>>> list(l_iter)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list(l_iter)
[]
```

The generator is an iterator, not an iterable and is also one shot.

```
>>> g = (x for x in range(3))
>>> hasattr(g, "__iter__")
True
>>> hasattr(g, "__next__")
True
>>> g == iter(g)
True
>>> 
>>> list(g)
[0, 1, 2]
>>> list(g)
[]
```

Comment: So if i understand correctly, the `__iter__` of an iterartor returns itself that's why `l_iter == iter(l_iter)` returns `True`, but `__iter__` of an iterables returns a fresh iterator every time correct ? So can you give example of how `__iter__` of list class looks like maybe ?

Comment: Yes. Its python so people can do crazy things but the advantage of an iterator returning itself is that something like an inner `for` keeps consuming the data. Iterables tend to pass unique iterators so that different `for` 's don't interfere with each other. I'll see what I can work up.